# Lyrik vs Poesie

Tags: difference, meaning, synonym

Both words in the title get translated as *poetry*.

How do they differ?<sup>1</sup>

Which of the two would be more appropriate to translate a title like *Anthology of 20th century German **poetry***?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> My first guess was that *Lyrik* and *Poesie* mapped respectively to *lyric poetry* and *poetry*, but I’m not sure anymore.</sup>

Comment: Was ist mit *Dichtung*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Poesy is a quite old word for *(literarische) Gattungen*. It consists of *Lyrik*, *Epik* and *Dramatik.*
That’s at least what the Poesy by Aristotle defines it.

But generally you can also just translate it as *Dichtung* like [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Poesie#Bedeutung3) did:

> - Dichtung als Kunstgattung; Dichtkunst
> - Dichtung als sprachliches Kunstwerk

The word *Poesie* is also used to highlight something special.
As it is said [on Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poesie):

> Der Begriff bezeichnet im übertragenen Sinn ferner eine bestimmte Qualität. So spricht man etwa von der „Poesie eines Moments“ oder einem „poetischen Film“ und meint damit in der Regel, dass von dem Bezeichneten eine sich der Sprache entziehende, oder über sie hinausgehende Wirkung ausgeht, etwas Stilles, ähnlich wie von einem Gedicht, das eine sich der Alltagssprache entziehende Wirkung entfaltet.

In Duden this is described as

> - poetischer Stimmungsgehalt, Zauber

Comment: Pretty sure there's at least one definition of _Dichtung_ missing ;)

Answer (score 3):

Poesie is split into three parts:
Lyrik, Epik and Dramatik.
Poesie is just a general word.

I would say, "Poesie" is just another word for "Dichtung".